# MySQL - Case/If statements

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing a query to fetch data from a table named `contracts`, with a join to the table `user_data` or `teams`. The table `contracts` has a column in it named `contracteeType`, in which I want to use as the conditional variable for the argument. In PHP code terms, this would be done as the following:

```
if ($contracteeType === 'user') {
  // SELECT data FROM user_data table
} else {
  // SELECT data FROM teams table
}
```

I have tried researching this, and I came across a CASE statement solution to the problem, but it doesn't appear to be working on my server. The following is what I had come up with:

```
SELECT * 
FROM contracts 
CASE 
    WHEN contracts.contracteeType = 'user' 
    THEN 'user_data' 
    WHEN contracts.contracteeType = 'team' 
    THEN 'teams' 
END as tableName 
CASE 
    WHEN contracts.contracteeType = 'user' 
    THEN 'userID' 
    WHEN contracts.contracteeType = 'team' 
    THEN 'teamID' 
END as colName 
INNER JOIN tableName 
ON tableName.colName = '.$contractID
```

How could I perform this task with my query, and fetch data from a table depending on the value from another?

Comment: Did you check your mysql error logs? Your syntax has errors.

Comment: This kind of problem *can* be indicative of poor design

Comment: No you can not have conditional table selection on query and more over if this is something needed then you need to use stored procedure using prepare statement with dynamic table name.

Comment: Yes. There are errors, which are indicated initially as `unrecognised keyword (near 'case')`. All errors after that are due to the CASE syntax kinda, not being right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can see an "if" working for you is to use a stored procedure. I find your question a little confusing, but I am sure that you can solve it by making and calling a stored procedure.

This approach has some drawbacks (lots of code, different from a simple query) however it has many good points (secure, fast as pre compiled and infinitely flexible for "PHP" type logic).

This is an example stored procedure...

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS MyProcedure; // 
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure()
BEGIN

SET @MyVarA = (SELECT cola FROM tablea);
SET @MyVarB = (SELECT colb FROM tableb);

IF @MyVarA = 'a' AND @MyVarB = 'b' THEN 
    SELECT A FROM B;
END IF

IF @MyVarA = 'd' AND @MyVarB = 'e' THEN 
    SELECT D FROM E;
END IF

END; //
```

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-routines.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html

Answer (score 1):

UNIONs are only good in small doses. Computing the result set requires temporary tables that will quickly eat through your memory allocation, and if you ever need to sort one there's no possible index to do it with. Also, if the tables have different schemas you column names are going to get jacked up.

In this case I'd try something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM contracts c
  LEFT JOIN user_data u
  ON c.type = 'user' AND c.user_id = u.id
  LEFT JOIN team_data t
  ON c.type = 'team' AND c.team_id = t.id
WHERE c.contract_id = :contract_id
```

But wonky queries like this are usually better addressed by re-evaluating your database schema.

Alternatively, just select the data from `contracts` first, and then issue a separate statement to get date from the user or team table.